# How to prove that the solutions of a linear system Ax=0 is a vector space over R?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, homogeneous-equation

How to prove that the set of solutions to a homogeneous linear system $Ax=0$ is a vector space over $R$ under usual addition and scalar multiplication? Can you guys provide me an answer for this?

Comment: $\ker A = \{x\mid Ax=0\}$ is a vector space. Prove that the sum of two solutions and the scalar multiple of a solution are also solutions.

Comment: Is it something like a1x1 + a2x2+..... +anxn =0

Comment: The hint below is fine.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** You seem to be getting hung up on the definitions. Keep in mind that you should be answering the following:

- For vectors $x$ and $y$: if $Ax = 0$ and $Ay = 0$, why should we believe that $A(x + y) = 0$?
- For a vector $x$ and scalar $\alpha$: if $Ax = 0$, why should we believe that $A(\alpha x) = 0$?

Once you have an answer for the above two questions, you will have proven that the set of all vectors satisfying $Ax = 0$ is *"a vector space over $\Bbb R$ under the usual addition and scalar multiplication"*.

Comment: Always A is not equal to 0. Is it?

Comment: @user462517 I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: In Ax=0, should we consider A is always not equal to zero?

Comment: $A$ is not necessarily equal to zero. However, the same applies if $A$ is equal to zero, so we shouldn't say that $A$ is necessarily non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

To show something that $W$ is a subspace of $V$, we must show that:

1) $W$ is non-empty

2) $W$ is closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication. This is:

$\forall x,y \in W: \forall a \in \mathbb{R}: x + y \in W, ax \in W$

So, let's check these things:

1) $A*0 = 0$, so $0 \in \{Z|AZ = 0\}:= K$. Hence $K \neq \emptyset$

2) If $X,Y \in K$, then $A(X+Y) = AX + AY = 0 + 0 = 0$ hence $X + Y \in K$

Also $A(aX) = a(AX)= a*0 = 0$, so $aX \in K$

Hence, $K$ is a subspace.

Comment: Here I have to show whether the Ax=0 is a vector space over R under addition and scalar multiplication. Not as a subspace

Comment: If you have shown that it is a subspace, then you have shown that it is a vector space.... A subspace is a vector space by definition.

Comment: Yeah ok. Thank you for your answer

Comment: If an answer helped you, you can accept it so other users know your question has been solved :)

Comment: The only answer is 0. Right? So this vector space has only one value and that is 0. Am I correct?

Comment: That depends on A. For example,  when $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, then $K = \mathbb{R^2}$, since any vector of $\mathbb{R^2}$ gets mapped on zero.